# Last iteration in foreach loop with Object Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have an object like this.

```
objName {
 item1 : someItem,
 item2 : someItem,
 item3 : someItem,
}
```

Now the number of property is dynamic and can be increase in unknown amount, I am performing a **foreach** loop in the property key on this object like this.

```
Object.keys(objName).forEach(itemNumber => {
console.log(itemNumber);
});
```

How am I going to detect the very last iteration of it to perform a new task?

Comment: The question is not clear

Comment: i need to detect the very last iteration like declaring a var number that will increment while the length of object's property is equal to var number but since I am new javascript object I do not know where to start.

Comment: the object length key here is 3 right?

Comment: Code updated sorry...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use index and array parameters to check if there is next element. You can also check if current index is equal length - 1 `index == arr.length - 1`

```js
let objName = {
 item1 : "someItem",
 item2 : "someItem",
 item3 : "someItem",
}

Object.keys(objName).forEach((item, index, arr) => {
  console.log(item);
  if(!arr[index + 1]) console.log('End')
});
```

Comment: by subtracting the length to 1 means that is the last item?

Comment: If you have 3 elements then length is 3 but index of last element will be 2 because it starts from 0.

Comment: can I ask what is arr stands for?

Comment: Its stands for array.

Comment: array of what? object and array is different right, sorry I am not so familiar with javascript object and its method

Comment: Its a reference to the array that forEach is being applied to in this case its an array of object keys.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass index and value to forEach function like the code below and use Object.keys(objName).length to get the object length then the last member objName[value]

```
 var objName = {
 item1 : "someItem",
 item2 : "someItem",
 item3 : "someItem3",
}
Object.keys(objName).forEach((value, index) => {
if(index==Object.keys(objName).length-1){
  console.log(objName[value]);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First find the length of the object like below:

```
var objLength= Object.keys(objName).length;
```

Then you can use like this:

```
var count = 0;

Object.keys(objName).forEach(item => {
    console.log(item);
    count++;
    if (count == objLength)
    {
        console.log("endOfLoop");
    }
});
```